# Only single memory upgrade slot in Toshiba Satellite M105?

Tags: laptop

I seem to see only one slot on the Toshiba Satellite M105-S1021 model even though the scan tool from crutial detected 2 slots that could be upgraded?

There is a single slot at the bottom of the latop. When you open it up, it has only a single memory slot which is empty. The OS reports that it already has 512MB memory.

Comment: Read the following link:
http://www.insidemylaptop.com/how-to-upgrade-memory-in-toshiba-satellite-m100m105-laptop/ This actualy help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the tear down instructions I found at http://www.irisvista.com/tech/laptops/Toshiba-Satellite-M105/take-apart-notebook-2.htm the second RAM slot appears to be under the keyboard.  It looks possible to get to, but a bit of a pain

Comment: Thanks! This worked really well, and the laptop now has 2 GB memory!

Answer (score 1):

The first (in this case I guess the second) slot is inside the case and not accessible. This is the easiest way to provide expansion on most laptops. HP and Dell have recently started doing something similar to make the upgrade process easier and ensure users don't upgrade using incompatible memory modules.

Answer (score 0):

It's under the keyboard.  When it's under the keyboard it usually isn't too hard to get at.  I say usually because some laptops are pain to do anything with.  This one doesn't look too bad.  Just take out the four screws on the bottom of the case at the back.  Then pry off the power button bezel.  Then take any screws out holding the top of the keyboard off and viola.  If that is too much of a pain a good computer shop should be able to do that for little or no extra cost.  At my shop we do regular memory upgrades free (with purchase of memory) and under the keyboard upgrades for 15 bucks extra.